# how to read html request body from nodejs by name

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

Hi I want to read radio button check result from html page

I made this html page

```
<form action="/question" method="post">
<% for (var i = 0; i < questionList.length; i++) { %>
    <h1> <%= questionList[i] %> </h1> <br>

    <% for (var j = 0; j < answerList[i].length; j++) { %>
        <% if(j === 0) { %>
            <input type="radio" name="<%= questionList[i] %>" id="<%= questionList[i] %>" value="<%=answerList[i][j] %>" checked="checked"> <%=answerList[i][j] %> <br>
        <% } %>

        <% if(j > 0) { %>
            <input type="radio" name="<%= questionList[i] %>" id="<%= questionList[i] %>" value="<%=answerList[i][j] %>"> <%=answerList[i][j] %> <br>
            <% } %>
    <% } %> 
<% } %>
```

Finished

questionList and answerList are array to show question and answer

I want to get a result to my nodejs router
my current code is below

```
app.post('/question', function(req, res){
    for(var i=0; i<questionList.length; i++){
        console.log(req.body.questionList[i]);
    }
});
```

but I got an error`TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined at /home/kwon/NODE/TASK/myChat/routes/routes.js:298:37 at callbacks`

If I print log of req.body then I got result below

```
{ 'Howoldareyou? ': '20', 'Whatisyourfavorite? ': 'sports' }
```

so I think they are saved in well in req.body
I don't know how to read 'Howoldareyou' and 'Whatisyourfavorit' data (each are stored in questionList)

Comment: how does `questionList` look like?

Comment: questionList is just an array of string containning question list my code is `var questionList=[];` I push the data read from .txt file and storing them that above variable

Comment: but the error says `questionList` is undefined. Try to see if it has values.

Comment: I already checked it. It has value

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
app.post('/question', function(req, res){
    for(var i=0; i<questionList.length; i++){
        console.log(req.body[questionList[i]] );
    }
});
```

Comment: Wow Thank you! It worked! But I still wonder why this code worked well. Can you introduce me any link or document  so i can understand and change it?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

Answer (score -1):

Dude you need bodyparser module to receive data from that way check for bodyparser that code is might be old because bodyparser comes included in express in old days but not anymore now